# Large unknown margin-left for Views blocks

Tags: views, blocks, theming

I have a lot of fighting against some unknown large margin-left , around 30px in all themes I start to work with (Zen, Adaptive Theme) - I think it's for Blocks generated by Views...

I haven't found yet where exactly this margin is generated - but I can see - my Main menu of 100% width starts at the front page's edge; if I made a custom HTML block - it starts with the page;

But when I insert several Views blocks - they doesn't start with the page, but some 30px from left of the page;

So, to even them out - I have always remember to put them some negative margin-left, at least some -10 or -20px to somehow even them out....

What it is? What exactly is creating this huge margin-left on the front page for Views blocks?

Comment: In order to make it easy to understand, please upload a screenshot of this margin problem.

Comment: have you tried inspecting the elements in a developer tool in FF or Chrome to see what the culprit might be?

Comment: Since this is some default margin I assumed everyone has seen it; I use Firebug always, but I haven't been able to determine where this particular Margin is coming from...

Comment: When I am highlighting the views block area - it clearly shows the block area starts with page, but not content...